# Deprecation warning in connexion regarding x-body-name

Tags: python, warnings, connexion

We've just upgraded connexion (to version 2.13.1) and now we're getting the following deprecation warnings when running unit tests:

> DeprecationWarning: x-body-name within the requestBody schema will be deprecated in the next major version. It should be provided directly under the requestBody instead.

This warning shows up even though we don't use `x-body-name` in the schema.

Is this a false positive message?

I see that this warning comes from [the following code](https://github.com/spec-first/connexion/pull/1475/files#diff-bdf30be2de6c3619889ec27e4b83268b50fa86d49bb01075cffac7f984ecf98bR284):

```
    x_body_name = sanitize(self.request_body.get('x-body-name', None))

    if not x_body_name:
        # x-body-name also accepted in the schema field for legacy connexion compat
        warnings.warn('x-body-name within the requestBody schema will be deprecated in the '
                      'next major version. It should be provided directly under '
                      'the requestBody instead.', DeprecationWarning)
        x_body_name = sanitize(self.body_schema.get('x-body-name', 'body'))
```

This seems to output the warning in ALL case where it's not defined in the body whether or not it's defined in the schema (even though it's optional). I verified this by changing the code in connexion to only warn if the name is defined in the schema.

Am I missing something? Are we using a deprecated feature without being aware of it?

Answer (score 1):

This was a defect in connexion, a [fix has been merged](https://github.com/spec-first/connexion/pull/1554) for future versions.